# Calling a Javascript Function on LoginError Event

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an ASP.NET login control placed within a simple JavaScript popup modal that I developed.  I then have the modal in an update panel so that I can get a response from the server on successful login.  When the LoginError event fires I want to call a JavaScript function that displays the modal popup; as on the button press, the popup div disappears.

I basically need to know how to change the CSS display attribute of an element within C# or how to call JavaScript within c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a javascript function in your page that handles the display of the modal popup.  Then, use something like this in the LoginError event:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, yourUpdatePanel.GetType(), "AutoPostBackScript", "yourJavascriptFunction();", true);
```

If you are using jquery for your modal popup you will probably have a few more hoops to jump through to prepare the selectors.  document.ready doesn't fire again after postback in an update panel.

Comment: I ended up reworking the problem to eliminate the postback, but this solves the question as asked.